# Net::DBus with ActiveState Perl

Tags: perl, dbus, activestate

Apologies If I misunderstood anything incorrectly, I am very new to DBus having beginner experience in Perl.

I am working for a project where I need to connect to a remote dbus (running on linux) from a window machine. I will be connecting to the remote system bus and will be invoking method calls, signals etc. I can not change the host machine to Linux as we have other development which is developed on windows platforms.

Perl provides a support for dbus using Net::DBus module, but this module is not available for window platforms.

http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Net-DBus/

It seems that there is also a windows port of dbus available at 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/windbus/

I am trying to build the Net-DBus module using this windows port of DBus, but's not working.

Appreciate your help, how to build such module.

Comment: ① Did you get WinDBus to work? ② If so, how did installing `Net::Dbus` via CPAN (not ppm) fail? ③ If you regularily require a unixoid system, but cannot leave Windows (and don't want virtualization or dual-boot), then you may want to look into Cygwin.